# Finding index where one sequence is greater than another

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays and I'd like to find the index at which the data in one array becomes greater than another.   The following code seems to do the trick but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
# For example
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(-10,10,0.01)
f1 = x+3.0
f2 = 2*x

cross_over_index = np.nonzero(f2 > f1)[0][0]
```

Comment: That's pretty much the way to do this in NumPy. For very large arrays, a Cython version that stops early would be faster.

Comment: Looks fine. Similar solution is `np.where(f2 > f1)[0][0]`.

Comment: Alternatively, `np.argmax(f2 > f1)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `True` without that nasty `[0][0]` at the end. But it's basically the same.

Comment: @Jamie - that was what i was looking for, something to get rid of the need for the trailing [0][0]

Comment: @Jaime Could you please post an official answer then, so that the questions is not flaged as unanswered any longer :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is only meaningful if the arrays are ordered, you can find the crossover point with a binary search that will be much faster for large arrays:

```
# Find first index of a2 > a1
def crossover(a1, a2):
    bottom = 0
    top = min(len(a1) - 1, len(a2) - 1)

    if a2[top] <= a1[top]:
        return -1

    while top > bottom:
        mid = (top + bottom) >> 1
        if a2[mid] > a1[mid]:
            top = mid
        else:
            bottom = mid + 1
    return top

f1 = [ (x + 20) for x in range(80) ]
f2 = [ (2 * x) for x in range(100) ]

print( crossover( f1, f2 ) )
```

This should (and does) print "21".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the solution of the equation *f<sub>1</sub>(x) = f<sub>2</sub>(x)*, you could also do this:

```
np.argmin(abs(f2-f1))
# 1300
```

and to get `x` there, of course

```
x[np.argmin(abs(f2-f1))]
# 3.0
```

But note that this will only sometimes give the same answer as what you technically asked for (which in this example returns `i0 --> 1301` and `x0 --> 3.01` ( which is the solution plus stepsize of `x`).